# Batch conversion via filelist.csv

Tags: bash, command-line, batch-jobs

I need to batch convert some video files from H264 to H265. I know my ffmpeg command line, I have a csv of file names with a relative path (I need the filelist to drive it as some files in the location are already converted). The only thing I'm having trouble with now is driving the conversion from the filelist.

My command line:

```
cat mkv-analysis.csv | while read file; do $(ffmpeg -i '$file' -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=23 -preset medium -c:a copy -c:s copy '${file%.mkv}_new.mkv'); done;
```

And a sample of data:

```
Folder.A/file.A.mkv
Folder.B/file_b.mkv
Folder_C/file.C.mkv
```

So, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, as I get "$file: No such file or directory" messages?

Comment: If any of the answers has solved this problem, please Accept it with the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are using single quotes around `$file` which means that the variable isn't expanded:

```
$ var="foo"
$ echo "$var"
foo
$ echo '$var'
$var
```

So, the command you are looking for is (with a few more improvements):

```
while read -r file; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=23 -preset medium -c:a copy -c:s copy "${file%.mkv}_new.mkv"
done < mkv-analysis.csv
```

Note that there's no need for `cat` and absolutely no point in running the command as a [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) (`$(command)`). That's only needed when you want to capture the output of a command in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
$ cat mkv-analysis.csv | xargs -I % ffmpeg ...
```

% is the argument, a file path in your case.

assuming that `mkv-analysis.csv` has the format:

```
file-path1
file-path2
...
```

If the format is different you'll have to prepare it with `awk`:
E.g.:

```
$ awk '...awk script...' mkv-analysis.csv | xargs ffmpeg ...
```

The main thing is that `xargs` feeds `ffmpeg` with files and at this stage `ffmpeg` should be able to find the file.